# Spring MVC return view url is not correctly build

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

The application which has the `pom.file` below uses Spring Boot & Spring MVC & Rest template. If I deploy the app (or start with Spring boot Application.java class) and navigate to `http://localhost:8080/app-name/user/{userID}` then I get this exception:

> HTTP Status 404 - /poc-app/user/WEB-INF/views/user.jsp

As you can see, it is appending the view with **"user"**. Here is the code, configuration and `pom.xml` file:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listAllUsers(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("users", getUsers());
    return "user-list";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showUserDetail(@PathVariable("userId") int userId, Model model) {
            //not checking the list with id, this is just for test
    UserBean bean1 = new UserBean();
    bean1.setBinNumber("123456");
    bean1.setFullName("User One");
    bean1.setGuid("abcdef");
    bean1.setShortName("User1");

    model.addAttribute("user",bean1);
    return "user";
}

private List<UserBean> getUsers(){
    List<UserBean> list = new ArrayList<UserBean>();

    UserBean bean1 = new UserBean();
    bean1.setBinNumber("123456");
    bean1.setFullName("User One");
    bean1.setGuid("abcdef");
    bean1.setShortName("User1");

    UserBean bean2 = new UserBean();
    bean2.setBinNumber("987654");
    bean2.setFullName("User Two");
    bean2.setGuid("xyzabc");
    bean2.setShortName("User2");

    UserBean bean3 = new UserBean();
    bean3.setBinNumber("555555");
    bean3.setFullName("User Three");
    bean3.setGuid("hghghg");
    bean3.setShortName("User3");

    list.add(bean1);
    list.add(bean2);
    list.add(bean3);

    return list;
}
```

}

---

**application.properties file**

```
server.port: 8080
management.port: 8001
management.address: 127.0.0.1

spring.view.prefix: WEB-INF/views/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

---

**Spring Boot Application.java**

```
@ComponentScan("com.company.project")
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProjectAdminWebPocApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VoucherAdminWebPocApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder   application) {
        return application.sources(VoucherAdminWebPocApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ErrorPageFilter errorPageFilter() {
        return new ErrorPageFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean disableSpringBootErrorFilter(ErrorPageFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

}
```

---

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>poc-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>poc-app</name>
    <description>Proof of concept project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Note: there is no problem if I navigate to  http://localhost:8080/app-name/user  - this works perfectly fine

Comment: Your view prefix should be `/WEB-INF/views/`... Notice the leading `/`...

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum thanks a lot. It helped! And this again proved that simple things can cause big problems :) btw if you could add this as an answer I could happily mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spring.view.prefix: WEB-INF/views/
```

You have your prefix configured as relative URLs instead of absolute URLs. Hence it will be added to the incoming request. To fix this make the URL absolute by adding a `/` to the beginning of it.

```
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
```